# Highlight datagridview row a color if it's currently being edited

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

It doesn't seem to find the column titled "Currently Editing" despite it being in there. If it matters, the gridview "querbox" is bound to an access database.

What I want it to do is, as long as something appears in the "editing ticket" field, it should be highlighted the salmon color.

How do I make it accomplish this?

I'm also wondering if there's a more efficient method than a for each, as this might get pretty laggy if the database grows in size.

```
 Private Sub querbox_DataSourceChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles querbox.DataSourceChanged

            For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DirectCast(sender, DataGridView).Rows

                If row.Cells("Currently Editing").Value.ToString.ToLower <> Nothing AndAlso row.Cells("Currently Editing").Value.ToString.ToLower <> Environment.UserName Then

                    row.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.Salmon

                Else

                    row.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.White

                End If

            Next


        End Sub
```